# Plot behind Ros and Joffrey

Tags: plot-explanation, character, game-of-thrones

At the end of Season 3 Episode 8, we see the prostitute Ros tied to the bedpost, her body riddled with arrows and Joffrey seated on a couch holding the long-bow.

Although we are well aware of Joffrey's maniacal and pyschopathic tendencies but I fail to understand what transpired in him killing her like that? And whatever happened to Ros being under the protection of Little Finger?

Comment: For the record, Ros dies in episode 6, The Climb, rather than 8

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ros was never really under Baelish's protection, merely another of his workers.  Towards the end of season 2, Varys employs Ros as a spy for him in order to follow Baelish's acts around King's Landing.

By the time of this episode, Baelish finds out who this traitor is and gives her back to Joffery for a little...fun as one may call it.

*The conversation between Baelish and Varys which unravels the plot is as follows:*

> **Varys:** Thwarting you has never
>   been my primary ambition, I promise you. Although who doesn't like to see
>   their friends fail now and then?
>
> **Baelish**: You're so right. For instance, when I thwarted your plan to give Sansa Stark to the Tyrells.
>   If I'm going to be honest, I did feel an unmistakable sense of enjoyment here.
>   *But your confidant, the one who fed you information about my plans, the one you swore to protect...you didn't bring her any enjoyment. And she didn't bring me any enjoyment. She was a bad investment on my part. Luckily, I have a friend who wanted to try something new. Something daring. And he was so grateful to me for providing this fresh experience.*

The confidant here being Ros and the friend being Joffrey .

Comment: Saying `Ros being under the protection of Little Finger` was wrong on my part but he definitely did favor her more than the other "_workers_". And Baelish finding out that she was a double-agent of sorts comes as a revelation to me. When did he discover this secret? Was it indicated in the TV series?

Comment: I don't think it was explicitly shown of his knowledge, just his implication and dialogue over the scene showing her corpse

Comment: Can you add the excerpts of the said dialogue to your answer.....I think it'll provide a sense of completeness to it.

Comment: Note to self:  find place where transcripts are kept on the internet.