# What happened with Ros?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

What was Ros final destination in Game of Thrones?
As I recall she was finally seen with Pycelle.

Comment: Related: [Plot behind Ros and Joffrey](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/11890/1006)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In season 3's episode "The Climb" Littlefinger discovers that she is a spy for Varys.

As a result he gives her to Joffrey as a gift, he proceeds to shoot her with his crossbow.

Warning Graphic image:

> [image]

Comment: She's not in the books; https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Ros#Game_of_Thrones:_Season_3:~:text=There%20is%20no%20character%20named%20Ros%20in%20the%20A%20Song%20of%20Ice%20and%20Fire%20novels

Comment: bad way of dying, she should have followed Theon advise not to leave in the first place.